# AngularJS data binding values directly into href

Tags: javascript, data-binding, angularjs

I'm not sure if this is a bug with AngularJS, Firefox, Chrome or whether it's simply a quirk...however,

When I do something like this

```
<a href="#/{{list.UUID}}/{{routeParams.status}}"> ...
```

In **Chrome** I get the values binding through correctly e.g.

```
...#/fa778108-5a0c-4675-974e-4cae0d9d6a86/active`
```

But in **Firefox** I get this

```
... #/{{list.UUID}}/{{routeParams.status}}
```

Anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "solution" I have found is to use `<a ng-href=" ...` but I'd still like to know *why* it doesn't work consistently...

Comment: What I would like to know is: why on the AngularJS home page, the "Wire up a Backend" example, in the list.html tab, do they use href and not ng-href?  Is it because of the $routeProvider pulls the html file/partial in?  I guess the bigger question is the same as Greg's: when do we need to use ng-href and when can we use href?  Should we always just use ng-href?

Comment: I still dont know the answer but I've gone through all my code and updated to ng-href...no problems to report but still curious!